# when you compare 2 strings what are you comparing exactly

Tags: javascript

with javascript when you compare 2 strings what are you comparing exactly

```js
return "hello" > "hola"
```

this will return false,  why ?

Comment: because "o" is greater than "e" in ascii code, or more specifically, unicode.

Comment: The strings, more accurately, a string's code points. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: See the [*Abstract Relational Comparison* algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

Answer (score 0):

The strings are compared character-by-character (h vs h), then (e vs o) until either one (or both) of the strings ends, or you get an inequality.  In this case 'e' is less than 'o'.

Every character is represented as a number.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison in javascript strings first compares characters one by one from the beginning. An string is bigger than another when the same index characters of the first different character in both strings is bigger than another.

```
"hello" > "hola"
"h" == "h"
"e" != "o" --> "e" < "o"
```

this is why the result is false;